# Unset in multidimentionnal array by key

Tags: php

I have this array and I would like to unset all the "downloads" arrays

```
    Array
(
    [assetIndex] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1.10
            [sha1] => 72241db3c0bdc39e39b202182ff0000da5271a1d
            [size] => 145874
            [url] => https://launchermeta.mojang.com/mc/assets/1.10/72241db3c0bdc39e39b202182ff0000da5271a1d/1.10.json
            [totalSize] => 122198775
        )

    [assets] => 1.10
    [downloads] => Array
        (
            [client] => Array
                (
                    [sha1] => dc8e75ac7274ff6af462b0dcec43c307de668e40
                    [size] => 8857653
                    [url] => https://launcher.mojang.com/mc/game/1.10.2/client/dc8e75ac7274ff6af462b0dcec43c307de668e40/client.jar
                )

            [server] => Array
                (
                    [sha1] => 3d501b23df53c548254f5e3f66492d178a48db63
                    [size] => 9459897
                    [url] => https://launcher.mojang.com/mc/game/1.10.2/server/3d501b23df53c548254f5e3f66492d178a48db63/server.jar
                )

        )

    [id] => 1.10.2
    [libraries] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => com.mojang:netty:1.6
                    [downloads] => Array
                        (
                            [artifact] => Array
                                (
                                    [size] => 7877
                                    [sha1] => 4b75825a06139752bd800d9e29c5fd55b8b1b1e4
                                    [path] => com/mojang/netty/1.6/netty-1.6.jar
                                    [url] => https://libraries.minecraft.net/com/mojang/netty/1.6/netty-1.6.jar
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => oshi-project:oshi-core:1.1
                    [downloads] => Array
                        (
                            [artifact] => Array
                                (
                                    [size] => 30973
                                    [sha1] => 9ddf7b048a8d701be231c0f4f95fd986198fd2d8
                                    [path] => oshi-project/oshi-core/1.1/oshi-core-1.1.jar
                                    [url] => https://libraries.minecraft.net/oshi-project/oshi-core/1.1/oshi-core-1.1.jar
                                )

                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => net.java.dev.jna:jna:3.4.0
                    [downloads] => Array
                        (
                            [artifact] => Array
                                (
                                    [size] => 1008730
                                    [sha1] => 803ff252fedbd395baffd43b37341dc4a150a554
                                    [path] => net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.4.0/jna-3.4.0.jar
                                    [url] => https://libraries.minecraft.net/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.4.0/jna-3.4.0.jar
                                )

                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => net.java.dev.jna:platform:3.4.0
                    [downloads] => Array
                        (
                            [artifact] => Array
                                (
                                    [size] => 913436
                                    [sha1] => e3f70017be8100d3d6923f50b3d2ee17714e9c13
                                    [path] => net/java/dev/jna/platform/3.4.0/platform-3.4.0.jar
                                    [url] => https://libraries.minecraft.net/net/java/dev/jna/platform/3.4.0/platform-3.4.0.jar
                                )

                        )

                )
        )
)
```

I am using search_array, and I am assuming that because it is multidimensional it isn't finding it. How can I search recursively?
I also tried a bunch of examples I found online but I can't find anything that suits my needs.

Comment: DID you know about anything to **unset** in PHP????

Comment: show what you've tried so far.

Comment: I do but not in a multidimentionnal array.

Answer (score 1):

what about this

```
function array_unset_recursive(&$array, $removeKey) {
    foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
        if($key == $removeKey){
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
        else if (is_array($value)) {
            array_unset_recursive($value, $removeKey);
        }
    }
}

array_unset_recursive($arr, 'downloads');
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to run `unset` for the main `downloads` index. And for the sub-arrays, just loop through your `$array['libraries']` and keep unsetting the sub array `downloads` field.

```
unset($array['downloads']); /* Unset the downloads field within the main array */

foreach ($array['libraries'] as &$arr) {
    unset($arr['downloads']); /* Unset the downloads field within the subarray */
}
```